# Theme switcher on localstorage observable service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, local-storage, observable

I implemented a dynamic theme switcher (with tutorial) in my angular app. It work's but when I reload website, the choice is not remembered.

I read about localStorage and i will use it but still doesn't work because I don't know how "where" I should get data from this localStorage, that the choice of the theme will be remembered when I reload the page.

I have this code:

**theme.service.ts** new version

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {
  private _themeDark: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  isDarkFunction() {
let value = localStorage.getItem('isDark');
this._themeDark.next(value);
return this._themeDark.asObservable();
  }

  isThemeDark = this.isDarkFunction();

  setDarkTheme(isThemeDark: boolean) {
    this._themeDark.next(isThemeDark);
    localStorage.setItem('isDark', JSON.stringify(isThemeDark));
  }

}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid switcher-container">
    <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="isThemeDark | async" (change)="toggleDarkTheme($event.checked)">Dark theme</mat-slide-toggle> 
</div>
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from '../services/theme.service'; 
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isThemeDark: Observable<boolean>; 

  constructor(
    private themeService: ThemeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isThemeDark = this.themeService.isThemeDark; 
  }

  toggleDarkTheme(checked: boolean) { 
    this.themeService.setDarkTheme(checked); 
  } 

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"; 
import { ThemeService } from "./services/theme.service"; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [ThemeService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  isThemeDark: Observable<boolean>; 


  constructor(
    public themeService: ThemeService) {

    }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.isThemeDark = this.themeService.isThemeDark;

  }

}
```

Please help,
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You might write something like the following in **theme.service.ts**.
I don't know if it will run flawlessly as is but the idea is to read from *localstorage* in `isThemeDark()`.

```javascript
isThemeDark() {
    let value = localStorage.getItem('isDark');
    this._themeDark.next(value);
    return this._themeDark.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I was updated theme.service.ts code in my post. Firstly this._themeDark.next(value) need argument of type boolean.

Comment: Yes, indeed I wrote that I was not sure about, I have not tried it. Anyway, the problem is the getItem type: try to put some console.log in order to set the correct value to the next method :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you when you do `localStorage.getItem('isDark')` the result is a string, not a boolean. Maybe try:

```
let value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isDark')) === true;
```

Also check manually if the localstorage is kept after a refresh. Some browsers have a setting to clear everything on refresh.